pySerial でのシリアル通信終了時にエラーが発生する
tkinterで作成したGUIアプリケーション上で、pySerialでシリアル通信を行おうとしていますが、ポートを閉じると Ser.readline() の部分でエラーが発生します。
ポートが開かれている間は受信待ちを行う構成にしていて、終了したい場合は キー入力時のイベントでSer.close() を実行し、ポートを閉じることで終了しています。
また、この受信待ちのループはマルチスレッドで行っています。
何故か直前の条件分岐ではじけません。
どなたか解決策をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示願います。
Windows 11
Python 3.12.5
pySerial 3.5
エラー内容
ReadFile failed (OSError(9, 'ハンドルが無効です。', None, 6))
もしくは
Attempting to use a port that is not open

コード
Ser = serial.Serial(PortName,19200,timeout = 1)

while Ser.is_open:
    try:
        if Ser is not None and Ser.is_open:
            if Ser._overlapped_read is not None:
                RecievedData = Ser.readline()


Ser._overlapped_readはドキュメントには書かれていない内部的な何かのようですが、それを諸々の準備も無く単独で使っても意味が無いのでは？ 例えばこんな記事 pass memoryview to win32.ReadFile for Pyserial readinto() function (あるいはこちらはPython2.7ですが PySerial Throwing 'NoneType' Exception During read()) の内容です。 名前と使われ方からすると in_waiting を使った方が良さそうですが。

あとC# APIの説明ですが、close直後のopenはせず少し待つようにという注釈がありますが、意識していますか？ Remarks - SerialPort.Close Method あるいはそうではなくて、単純に PySerial の close を行った後に readline が実行されているのでは？ while Ser.is_open: とか Ser._overlapped_read(内容的には上記コメントのin_waitingか？) というシリアルポートオブジェクトに依存した条件だけではなく、自分自身のプログラム上で既に close を行ったかどうかの情報を保持・更新して、readline を実行するかどうかの判定に追加してみてはどうでしょう？

@kunif さん
コメントありがとうございます。
Ser._overlapped_readの条件分岐は、ポートクローズ時にSer.readline()で、'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hEvent'というエラーが発生するため、対策として入れています。(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919174/pyserial-throwing-nonetype-exception-during-read)
ポートクローズ後の待機についてはあまり意識していませんでしたが、今回のエラーは、初めてポートをクローズする場合にも発生しているため、あまり関係がないかと思われます。

見る方向が逆なのかもしれません。つまりreadline処理中で行末文字(デフォルトはb'\n'？)の受信を待っている時にcloseが呼び出されるのでは？ プログラム中にスレッド間で共有できる readline処理中を示すグローバル変数等を定義して RecievedData = Ser.readline() の前後でオン/オフを切り替えて、キー入力をトリガに closeする前に判定し、readline処理中ならばcloseしないようにしてみてはどうでしょう？ Python creating a shared variable between threads さらに readline処理中だからclose出来なかったとしてclose待ちを示すグローバル変数等を定義して、readline終了時にclose待ちならcloseする処理を加えるのも良いかもしれません。

こんなサンプルがやろうとしていることに近いかもしれませんね。Pythonのサンプルコード あとはアプリケーションが動作中にポートのOpen/Closeを自在に行う必要が無ければ、そもそもプログラムを終了させようとしてGUIのメインループが終わった後にポートをcloseするとか。Pythonでシリアル通信に挑戦

@kunif さん
数多くアドバイスいただきまして、ありがとうございます。
アドバイスを参考に、in_waitingを使用して、バッファにあるデータのバイト数が0だった場合にデータを読み取らない条件分岐を追加して、一旦エラーは回避できました。
ありがとうございました。
